# Spark Streaming: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/api/TopicMetadataRequest

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I wrote a spark streaming application which reads data from kafka. 
I have build the jar with `spark1.6.0` and `kafka0.8.2.2`. 
I am using kafka direct stream apis:

`KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)`

When i run the application in yarn-client mode , it runs successfully, but when i run in yarn-cluster mode it fails with following exception:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/api/TopicMetadataRequest.
```

I have packaged kafka classes in the application jar and even during runtime, kafka/api/TopicMetadataRequest gets loaded up from the application jar.

As per my understanding,  `NoClassDefFoundError` would occur when there is a version mismatch between compile and runtime.

**-----------EDIT------------**

My .sbt has folllowng block:

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0" % "provided",   
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0" % "provided",   
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0" % "provided",   
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.0" % "provided",   
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.0",    
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.8.2.2",   
"org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-web" % "3.0.7.RELEASE",   
"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "3.0.0-M12" % "test",   
"junit" % "junit" % "4.11",  
"com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.10" % "2.4.0-M2",   
"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2.5" )  



    mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>   {
        case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => MergeStrategy.first    } }
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this or why is this exception occurring ?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `SPARK.JARS` setting to send your jar to the cluster.

Comment: as per the documentation we dont need to give any option for application jar . right ? `$ ./bin/spark-submit --class path.to.your.Class --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster [options] <app jar> [app options]`

Comment: How did you do that _"I have build the jar with spark1.6.0 and kafka0.8.2.2"_ How did you define the dependency on `spark-streaming-kafka` Spark module?

Comment: i added dependency in sbt file :
`"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.0", 
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.8.2.2",`

Comment: you are building an 'assembly', right?

Comment: yes , fat jar . kafka/api/TopicMetadataRequest is present in the jar. Even it gets loaded up during runtime . I used classloader apis to verify that kafka/api/TopicMetadataRequest.class is present in classpath.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the entire `build.sbt`?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

`KafkaUtils` is not available in Spark and you have to add `spark-streaming-kafka` module separately to your Spark application.

You should use `--packages` command-line option.

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10:1.6.0
```

Use proper versions for Scala and Spark.

Comment: I think issue would be something else , since this is working in yarn-client mode . Also I  have already added `spark-streaming-kafka` : 
`"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.0", "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.8.2.2",`